# How to update parameters in SSIS?

Tags: sql, parameters, ssis, parameter-passing

I would like to know if I can update the parameter values (mainly timestamp) automatically using any SQL query. Please don't suggest me to use Environments, as the value is constantly changing and I need them to be updated automatically when I run.

Comment: You can set/update variables.  Don't know about parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may follow these steps to config your parameter:

1. create a variable, e.g. User::starttime
2. add an '[Execute SQL Task'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx):  specify the connection info and the query. e.g. `SELECT STARTTIME FROM TABLE`. set the **ResultSet** to 'Single row'. in the **ResultSet Tab** map the result name and variable name.
3. after the 'Execute SQL Task' executed, the variable 'User::starttime' will be set to the SQL result.
4. use the variable User::starttime as your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please go throw below link you can use any query output as veritable.

http://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/